# Android Studio mergeReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported my project from eclipse to Android Studio every thing works find but when I try to build gradle
`Error:Execution failed for task ':iCampusLibrary:mergeReleaseResources'`.
Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
below is my gradle

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:iAlBarsh_New:assembleDebug]
:iAlBarsh_New:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iAlBarsh_New:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iAlBarsh_New:checkDebugManifest
:iAlBarsh_New:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:compileLint
:iCampusLibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
:iCampusLibrary:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:compileLint
:loadMoreListView:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:checkReleaseManifest
:loadMoreListView:prepareReleaseDependencies
:loadMoreListView:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:loadMoreListView:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:compileLint
:pTR:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:checkReleaseManifest
:pTR:prepareReleaseDependencies
:pTR:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pTR:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:compileLint
:slidingMenuLibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
:slidingMenuLibrary:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies
:slidingMenuLibrary:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:slidingMenuLibrary:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComJoanzapataPdfviewAndroidPdfview104Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareComRoomoramaCaldroid110Library UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareIAlBarsh_NewLoadMoreListViewUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareIAlBarsh_NewPTRUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareIAlBarsh_NewSlidingMenuLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies
:iCampusLibrary:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:iCampusLibrary:mergeReleaseResources
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/splashscreen.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abs__ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abs__ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/splashscreen.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/profile_female.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/iAlBarsh_New/pTR/unspecified/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abs__ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/splashscreen.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/iAlBarsh_New/pTR/unspecified/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/profile_male.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/splashscreen.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/left_bl.9.png malformed.
AAPT:        No marked region found along edge.
AAPT:        Found along top edge.
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/iAlBarsh_New/pTR/unspecified/res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/logo_head.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abs__ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/splashscreen.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/attachment.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/login.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/close_button.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/right_bl.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/right_bl.9.png malformed.
AAPT:        No marked region found along edge.
AAPT:        Found along top edge.
AAPT: /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
:iCampusLibrary:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':iCampusLibrary:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 15.838 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Please help I struggling with issue and cant find any solution ,any help will be appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will not catch 9-patch errors. If you look at the output, you have invalid 9-patch files.

```
AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image /media/neosoft/95ca03b9-9771-4d00-8411-21d958b0ecfe/AndroidStudioProject/iAlBarsh_New/iCampusLibrary/src/main/res/drawable/right_bl.9.png malformed.
AAPT:        No marked region found along edge.
AAPT:        Found along top edge.
```

These may even appear fine when testing, but you need to specify all of the 9-patch features for it to work properly on all platforms, etc. Edit and fix those files and it should work.

EDIT:

In your case the error is saying that the asset does not have all edges marked properly for 9-patch. If you change the asset to a regular `.png` it will build, but it may look wrong in the app.

You can use a 9-patch editor to correct it, but you do need to be familiar with how to "fix" the image. Here is a reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: how do I solve this changing .9.png to .png will it work?